# Ordering 3 1d numpy array to obtain a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datagrid

I have 3 numpy array containing `x, y` and `f(x,y) values`. They are ordered one with respect to the others but completely disordered in itself.
Let's say, for sake of simplicity, that `f=x+y
they are

```
x | y | f
1 | 2 | 3
5 | 1 | 6
....
```

And let's suppose that I know I have all the points to fill a grid.

I would like to obtain a mesh grid or a 2d python numpy array from it.

In c I know how to do it, but I know in python `"for"` cycles with element substitutions are avoidable and discouraged...

Do you have any solution?

Thanks

Comment: to be clear are they each distinct np.arrays that look like [x,y,f(x,y)]?  Can you tell me what your expected output is?  all three as rows in a big 2d np array?

Comment: no there are three numpy arrays that look like:
[x1,x2,...]
[y1,y2,...]
[f(x1,y1),f(x2,y2)...]
I want to obtain a 2d numpy array with the values of f(x,y) ordered like a grid, with axis x and y. Is it clearer now?

Comment: ahhhh yes.  ok i understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a the concatenate function.

```
a = np.array([[x1, y1, f1]])
b = np.array([[x2, y2, f2]])
np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: No I don't want to concatenate two arrays. I commented my question. I hope now it is clearer.